# Not able to share entire desktop while using google hangouts or appear.in

Tags: fedora, x11, xorg

I am not able to share my desktop when I am using hangouts or appear.in feature to share your entire desktop.
Whenever I click to share the entire desktop there is a black screen and the cursor movement is only visible to the user connected on call. But when i select and share a particular window/application the share works fine.The OS which I am using is fedora 24.The feature to share entire desktop doesn't work in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.
Earlier i had used the same feature and it was working fine.
Please help me out with this.

Model for graphics card : NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M]
Kernel Drivers in use : nouveau,

Model of Laptop :HP ENVY J110TX using fedora 25 at the moment.

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work". Do you get error messages? Have you checked Hangouts' bug reports, etc.?

Comment: Doesn't work means when i select to share the entire desktop it shows a black screen.No i haven't checked for error messages.How  to check them?

Comment: Shut down all open instances of your preferred Firefox or Chrome. Open a terminal window. Run `firefox` or `google-chrome`  in that window. Errors may be printed to the screen, which you can copy'n'paste into your question.

Comment: I have tried the way you told and the errors are not logged on terminal.

Comment: I have also formatted my fedora system. I use it in dual boot with windows and in windows the desktop/entire screen sharing is working. But in my fedora the entire screen share doesnt work even after formatting.

Comment: Please add hardware details to your question. Make & model of computer and in particular make & model of the graphics card. Also which driver you are using for it.

Comment: Same problem here. I'm using fedora 25 on a Asus k501 model, I thing it could be related with the new display mode used since fedora 25. Haven't tested so it could be a wild guess

Comment: Same problem here. I'm using fedora 25 on a Asus k501 model, I thing it could be related with the new display mode used since fedora 25. Haven't tested so it could be a wild guess

Answer (score 7):

This is a known screensharing bug with Wayland:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1369218

Unfortunately the easiest fix is to not use Wayland. You can use Gnome with Xorg at the login screen by selecting the gear icon before logging in, and you can use Xorg by default by modifying your /etc/gdm/custom.conf file and un-commenting `WaylandEnable=false`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: For Debian 10 https://support.google.com/meet/thread/65557706?hl=en&msgid=65579053

Answer (score 4):

Uncommenting `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` worked for me.

Comment: Does this really apply to the given question? There's no mention of Wayland in the Question, or of Google Hangouts in your Answer.

Comment: This answer doesn’t provide enough detail, but it does apply to the question, and it does provide an answer to it, or at least it attempts to — there’s a fair chance the sharing problem is related to using Wayland rather than X11.

Comment: I had the same issue as OP, google brought me here, there wasn't a detailed answer thus I added one since others might arrive here by the same means.

Answer (score 1):

Modify `chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer` set it as enabled and restart chrome. You'll be able to share your entire screen or any single window.

Comment: this did give me the option to select my desktop in fedora 36.  unfortunately for me brave talk crashes as soon as i click stop sharing, every time...

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 25 don't use xorg, I have the same model as you and I got the same error, but when I enter using xorg everything works fine